# Wiped hard disk completely removing all partitions - now computer won't start from Ubuntu live stick or Windows ISO

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, secure-boot

Today I wiped the hard disk of an Asus Windows computer from 2015. It has Secure Boot. I used an Ubuntu Live stick, opened the Disks app and removed all partitions, then used Shred to wipe the entire disk. The disk had sensitive data on it and had to be wiped

After this, I wanted to reinstall Windows, so I created a Windows USB stick, but it didn't want to boot from that stick. I tried the Ubuntu stick as well. I've used this method before on other computers, so I thought I was safe doing this.

Every time I boot I end up in the BIOS/UEFI configuration screen. I've set the boot order, but it doesn't matter. I've looked into Secure boot options, but can't find anything.

In the UEFI/BIOS settings I can't disable Secure Boot for some reason. It simply says 'enabled', no dropdown menu option or anything.

**How can I reinstall this computer?**

Comment: have you tried "load optimized defaults"? https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1039491/

Comment: Secure Boot stays enabled and I don't see how I can disable it

Comment: @nycynik yes I did, but I expect this to reset the UEFI settings, and it doesn't. It keeps settings I've changed.

Comment: Could be wrong but I think your starting point needs to be to find a way to disable Secure Boot, perhaps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCxoOyUQqUE

Comment: I've disabled Secure Boot by clearing the keys. But it keept rebooting into the BIOS. There I see the USB stick as first and only boot option, and nothing happens.

Comment: First, Ubuntu and most other recent Linux distros can be installed with Secure Boot *enabled*, and I've done so many times, so likely that is *not* the issue. Second, create the USB with a different tool, to see if that is the issue. If you've used UNetbootin, try Rufus, or vice versa. Third, try selecting device from the *boot menu*, not from BIOS/UEFI: https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/asus-boot-menu.html

Comment: Yes I've installed Ubuntu and Windows many times, with and without Secure Boot, with and without completely erasing the harddisk. It turns out that the stick was the problem. I've used dd on a Mac to write both the Windows and Ubuntu iso, and apparently that was the problem. Using an older stick it suddenly worked again. Thanks for all the support!